# Drag and drop not working first time if helper dimensions aren't set

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

If I drag an object on another element, it doesn't work the first time, but it works the second time.

The cause seems to be that my helper element is an image and it doesn't have a width & height set to it.

This is the code:

**HTML**

```
    <div class="target"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .target {
        width: 63px;
        height: 63px;
        background: rgb(185, 185, 185);
        position: relative;
    }

    .helper {
        background: pink;
    }

    .box {
        width: 63px;
        height: 63px;
        background: orange;    
    }

    .element {
        width: 63px;
        height: 63px;
        background: navy;
        position: absolute;
        left: 200px;
        top: 10px;
    }
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".element").draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    helper: function () {
        return $('<img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/tsgk-cctld-territories-icons-flags-pack-v---borderless/16/saint_helier.png" class="helper"></img>');
    },
    snap: ".target"
});

$('.target').droppable( {
    accept: ".element",
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: function(event, ui){
        var tile = $('<div class="box"><span>Tile</span></div>');
        $(".target").append(tile);
    }
});
```

If I add height and width to the **.helper** class it works as expected.

Here is the link to the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZzetJ/1/

I want to understand why is it working the second time, and why does it need a height and a width set?

**EDIT**:

From the comments below I see that people could not reproduce the issues.

For me it's not working on Chrome and Firefox, but works on IE9. Make sure to have a clear cache before running it.

Chrome version:  27.0.1453.110 m

Repro steps:

1. Use Chrome and go incognito by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+N.
2. Go to jsfiddle.net/ZzetJ/1/
3. Drag the blue div on top of the gray div.

   **Result:** You should see an image when dragged, and when the drop occurs the gray div should have change to orange. In this case it fails.
4. Drag the blue div again on top of the gray div.

   **Result:** The gray div changes successfully to orange.
5. Open a new tab in the same browser.
6. Go to jsfiddle.net/ZzetJ/1/
7. Drag the blue div on top of the gray div.

   **Result:** The gray div changes to orange.

So make sure to clear the cache.

Comment: what browse are you using? It's working in IE8 and Chrome

Comment: works 'fine' on chrome